# Printing from a file using readlines - new lines are doubled

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is

```
def print_words():
    letter=input("Enter First Letter:\n")
    file=open("english.txt", "r")
    words=[]
    for word in file.readlines():
        words.append(word)
        if word[0].lower()==letter.lower():
            print(word)

print_words()
```

My output has an empty line after every line that it prints for some reason. Any advice?

Comment: You should edit your question with your output, and the contents (or partial contents) of `english.txt`

Comment: off-topic, but you really shouldn't open files without closing them. Best of all,use the `with` statement so you don't have to close it manually.

Comment: try `print(word, end='')`

Answer (score 4):

`file.readlines` returns an array with all the lines, however it does not remove the trailing new line character (e.g. `['hello\n', 'bye\n']`).

When you print them, it's printing out the embedded new line character plus another new line inserted by `print` itself.

There are two ways to simply fix this:

1. Tell `print` *not* to insert a new line:

```py
print(word, end='')
```

2. Remove the trailing `\n` from each word:

```py
word = word.strip()
# Or, if you want to be extremely specific: word = word.strip('\n')
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot the end='' part. This is my first programming language I'm doing in ~ 8 years so I'm very rusty

Answer (score 0):

When you have that kind of issues, the best way to understand it is to print visible characters around your output:

```py
def print_words():
    letter=input("Enter First Letter:\n")
    file=open("english.txt", "r")
    words=[]
    for word in file.readlines():
        words.append(word)
        if word[0].lower()==letter.lower():
            print("-", word, "-")

print_words()
```

By doing so you can already have a vague idea of the origin of the problem, after entering a `j`:

```
- je suis là
 -
- je sais
 -
```

As suggested you could even use `print(repr(word))` which would instead output:

```
'je suis là\n'
'je sais \n'
```

The `word` contains the whole line, including the end of line. 
A quick fix would be to print without including a new line `print(word, end="")`.

Comment: The best way to debug values (especially strings) is to use `repr`.